# How can an assignment statement "x = y := f(x)" be done when using assignment expressions in Python?

Tags: python, pep, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

I read [in Twitter](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1014210487112818689):

> #Python news: Guido accepted PEP 572.  Python now has assignment expressions.
>
> ```
>  if (match := (pattern.search) pattern.search(data)) is not None:
>     print((match.group) mo.group(1))
>
>  filtered_data = [y for x in data if (y := f(x)) is not None]
> ```
>
> <sub>(correction mine in the 2nd line of code)</sub>

As indicated, [PEP 572 -- Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) describes this to be present in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html):

> This is a proposal for creating a way to assign to variables within an expression using the notation `NAME := expr`.

I've gone through the description and examples and I see this is a convenient way to avoid repetitions of either calls or assignments, so instead of:

```
match1 = pattern1.match(data)
match2 = pattern2.match(data)
if match1:
    return match1.group(1)
elif match2:
    return match2.group(2)
```

or the more efficient:

```
match1 = pattern1.match(data)
if match1:
    return match1.group(1)
else:
    match2 = pattern2.match(data)
    if match2:
        return match2.group(2)
```

One now can say:

```
if match1 := pattern1.match(data):
    return match1.group(1)
elif match2 := pattern2.match(data):
    return match2.group(2)
```

Similarly, one can now say:

```
if any(len(longline := line) >= 100 for line in lines):
    print("Extremely long line:", longline)
```

However, I do not understand how this example given in the PEP is not valid:

> ```
> y0 = y1 := f(x)  # INVALID
> ```

Will it be correct to say `y0 = (y1 := f(x))`? How could it be used?

<sub>Foot note for those who wonder where will this be available: I already installed [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) and it does not work there, since the PEP currently shows as "Status: Draft". However, the PEP talks about *Proof of concept / reference implementation ([https://github.com/Rosuav/cpython/tree/assignment-expressions)](https://github.com/Rosuav/cpython/tree/assignment-expressions)_)*, so it is a matter of using their Python 3.8 alpha 0 version that includes it.</sub>

Comment: This is [in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases).

Comment: @user2357112 yes thanks, this is where I took it from. This is why I ask how can it be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [explicitly stated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) in the PEP,

> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level in the right hand side of an assignment statement; for example, the following is not allowed:
>
> ```
> y0 = y1 := f(x)  # INVALID
> ```
>
> Again, this rule is included to avoid two visually similar ways of saying the same thing.

And [later](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#relative-precedence-of),

> As follows from section "Exceptional cases" above, it is never allowed at the same level as `=`. In case a different grouping is desired, parentheses should be used.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> # INVALID
> x = y := 0
>
> # Valid alternative
> x = (y := 0)
> ```